# Where is su configuration in the linux buildroot menuconfig

Tags: linux, menu, config, su, buildroot

The sudo is in the Target packages/Shell and utilites menu of the linux buildroot menu configuration.
But I can't fine su utility.

Where can I select the su utility in the linux buildroot menuconfig?

Comment: `su` is a necessary component of a linux system, while `sudo` is an optional convenience. I'm unfamiliar with buildroot, but I'd be surprised if you had the option to disable it. This question would be on topic at https://unix.stackexchange.com (or even [su]), but is not on topic on [so].

Comment: When using Buildroot, the `su` utility is typically built as part of Busybox rather than as a separate executable.  IOW you need to use `make busybox-menuconfig`.

Answer (score 1):

`su` command is part of busybox like others said.

You will find sudo package  with `make menuconfig`

```
Target packages  --->
    Shell and utilities  --->
        [ ] sudo
```

Comment: Important to mention that this is 'make menuconfig' of busybox, not of buildroot. To reach that from a buildroot setup, run 'make busybox-menuconfig' as explained further up